# Can't use list of FXML buttons

Tags: java, javafx

I have 9 buttons annotated with @FXML, which I want to use in a list. Buttons work correctly when I use them directly. But when I try to access them from list, I get NullPointer, and debugger shows, that my list has only null values

```
@FXML
private ToggleButton b11
//..
@FXML
private ToggleButton b33    
@FXML
private List buttons = [b11, b12, b13, b21, b22, b23, b31, b32, b33]
```

Example of method, which throws NullPointer

```
void reset(ActionEvent e) {
    def rand = new Random()
    def b = buttons.get(rand.nextInt(buttons.size()))      
    b.setSelected(true)
}
```

Comment: FXML is not capable of injecting instances into a collection (though you could declare the collection in the FXML file and then inject that collection). Also, the Java code you show us for declaring the `buttons` field is illegal. If you have a large number of buttons then consider creating them inside the controller, via the `initialize` method, instead of in the FXML file.

Comment: I moved initialization of buttons list to initialize() method and now it is working. Not sure if this is clean and correct code, but thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: @Slaw "FXML is not capable of injecting instances into a collection" -> I don't think this is correct, see the [introduction to fxml document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements) section on instance declarations (e.g. the `fx:factory` and `fx:reference` sections).  Though it can be done, I have no idea if it would be an appropriate solution for the asker.  Likely, initializing of the collection in the `initialize()` method, as he ended up doing it, is probably best for him.

Comment: @jewelsea What the OP was trying to do, or at least what I _believe_ the OP was trying to do, is not possible. That is, have the `FXMLLoader` automatically collect the elements into a collection and inject it without explicitly creating the collection. You can definitely do it if you declare the collection in the FXML file, optionally via `fx:factory`, and use `fx:reference` to add the elements to it, then inject the collection. Or you might be able to declare (and initialize) the collection in the controller and reference it via `fx:controller`, but not sure on that one.

Comment: @jewelsea Decided to add an answer showcasing both solutions. I agree that what the OP ended up doing is likely the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to happen is for the `FXMLLoader` to see the `List` field and automatically create a list (of some type) and add your buttons to it, then that is not possible with FXML. Given how you seem to be naming your buttons it would be better to initialize them in the controller, via the `initialize` method, instead of in the FXML file.

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Controller {

  // notice I declared the type argument; don't use raw types
  private List<ToggleButton> buttons;

  @FXML private GridPane grid;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
        ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton();
        // configure button...
        buttons.add(button);
        grid.add(button, col, row);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is likely the cleanest approach, and it definitely scales better—you can't loop in an FXML file.

However, you *could* declare the list in the FXML file and then inject the list instead of using the above solution.

```xml
<?import java.util.ArrayList?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<GridPane fx:id="grid" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" 
          fx:controller="com.example.Controller">
  <children>
    <ToggleButton fx:id="x" GridPane.columnIndex="..." GridPane.rowIndex="..."/>
    <ToggleButton fx:id="y" GridPane.columnIndex="..." GridPane.rowIndex="..."/>
    <ToggleButton fx:id="z" GridPane.columnIndex="..." GridPane.rowIndex="..."/>
    <!-- ... -->
  </children>
  
  <fx:define>
    <!-- Need to annotate 'buttons' with @FXML -->
    <ArrayList fx:id="buttons">
      <fx:reference source="x"/>
      <fx:reference source="y"/>
      <fx:reference source="z"/>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ArrayList>
  </fx:define>
</GridPane>
```

But as you can see, this is more difficult to maintain, at least in my opinion, and is more tedious, especially if you have a lot of buttons.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response! As you might have already read, I used a combination of your first approach and mine. The problem of initialization buttons in a controller is that I made .fxml file with SceneBuilder, and I find it pretty inconvenient to put a lot of button configuration in code. What I have now is 9 fields with @FXML annotation and a small initialize() method with buttons list.

Answer (score 1):

Slaw's answer is good for a general-purpose solution for initializing a list when FXML is involved.

**Specific solution for toggles**

For your specific task, you are working with `ToggleButton`s.  For those, there is already a holder and manager class called [`ToggleGroup`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html), which I would advise you to use, rather than initializing your own custom button list.

For setting a toggle group, then you can do that completely in FXML using SceneBuilder with no additional code to maintain in the Controller `initialize()` method.

In SceneBuilder, "Toggle Group" is an editable property of `ToggleButton` (look for it in the property list for the toggle button in the SceneBuilder UI). SceneBuilder will produce FXML to associate the toggle buttons to the toggle group. Put an `@FXML` reference to your toggle group in your controller and you can get the associated list of toggles from the group, using [`yourToggleGroup.getToggles()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html#getToggles()).

**Example application**

[image: screenshot]

*sample/FruitSelectionController.java*

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

import java.util.Random;

public class FruitSelectionController {

    private static final Random random = new Random(42);

    @FXML private ToggleGroup fruitSelectionToggleGroup;
    @FXML private ToggleButton fruitSelectionButton1;
    @FXML private ToggleButton fruitSelectionButton2;
    @FXML private ToggleButton fruitSelectionButton3;

    @FXML
    void selectRandom(ActionEvent event) {
        ObservableList<Toggle> toggles = fruitSelectionToggleGroup.getToggles();

        fruitSelectionToggleGroup.selectToggle(
                toggles.get(
                        random.nextInt(toggles.size())
                )
        );
    }

}
```

*sample/FruitSelectionApp.java*

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FruitSelectionApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
                getClass().getResource(
                        "fruit-selection.fxml"
                )
        );

        Parent root = loader.load();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*sample/fruit-selection.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.FruitSelectionController">
   <children>
      <ToggleButton fx:id="fruitSelectionButton1" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Apples">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="fruitSelectionToggleGroup" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton fx:id="fruitSelectionButton2" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Oranges" toggleGroup="$fruitSelectionToggleGroup" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="fruitSelectionButton3" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pears" toggleGroup="$fruitSelectionToggleGroup" />
      <Separator />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectRandom" text="Select Random" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

**Choose the Appropriate Toggle Type**

When in a group, ToggleButtons and RadioButtons are similar but slightly different in behavior.

From the ToggleButton documentation:

> Unlike RadioButtons, ToggleButtons in a ToggleGroup do not attempt to force at least one selected ToggleButton in the group. That is, if a ToggleButton is selected, clicking on it will cause it to become unselected. With RadioButton, clicking on the selected button in the group will have no effect.

So make sure you choose the appropriate toggle type for your application.